# Large Google OAuth2 consent screen when connecting with Google Apps account

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, google-oauth

When logging into our app using OAuth2, regular Google (ie. gmail) accounts are presented with the consent screen once, and then no longer prompted. When I log in using our Google Apps based Google account, I am prompted with the same screen every time that mentions "Your domain administrator has approved access to X". Additionally - the consent screen has a huge (512x512) image of my Google avatar.

[image]

Any insight as to why these are different?

I am requesting the following scope ['profile', 'email', ] and I have set the 'access_type' to 'offline' so that I can get a refresh token.

Fixing this issue is a pre-cursor to putting our app on GAMv2.

Comment: Are you using a service account for the domain individuals?

Comment: @soitof Not sure what you mean - can you clarify?

Answer (score 3):

Even with marketplace apps, a consent screen is shown when a 'offline' is requested. Since the admin already approved the app, an abbreviated screen is shown. However, it should only be shown once per user.

If you're seeing it repeatedly, make sure:

- You're not specifying approval_prompt=force in the request. This will result in the consent screen being shown each time
- You're actually exchanging the authorization code for a refresh token.

As for the UI, that's an issue on Google's end with the styling of that page.

Comment: I have confirmed that we are not sending **approval_prompt=force** in the request. I am definitely requesting offline access, and would expect the consent screen the first time, but the screen is coming up every time.

Answer (score 1):

Are those requested scopes (profile, email) different from application marketplace scopes? If so, try to request the same scopes as your application have in marketplace SDK scopes list.

Comment: They are equivalent scopes. I am requesting the 'profile' and 'email' scope, however the Google Apps console has the deprecated scopes automatically added for you (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile). If you try to add the 'email' or 'profile' scope it reports "Duplicate auth scope. Alias for ...".